# Remplazar el contenido de varios divs con varios callbacks en PHP

Tags: php

Estoy intentado remplazar el contenido que hay dentro de varios divs con varios callbacks. El nombre de los callbacks que quiero usar están dentro de esos divs:

```
function googlemaps(){
    return 'Google Maps muestra su contenido'
}

function socialicons(){
    return 'Social Icons muestra su contenido';
}

function callaction(){
    return 'Call Action hace sus cosas y muestra su contenido';
}

$builder = '
    <div class="row">
        <div class="column col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <!--moz-module-->
            <div class="moz-widget">
            <div class="moz-widget-id">[moz_widget]googlemaps[/moz_widget]</div>
            </div>
            <!--/moz-module-->
        </div>

        <div class="column col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <!--moz-module-->
            <div class="moz-widget">
            <div class="moz-widget-id">moz_widget]videos[/moz_widget</div>
            </div>
            <!--/moz-module-->
        </div>

        <div class="column col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
            <!--moz-module-->
            <div class="moz-widget">
            <div class="moz-widget-id">[moz_widget]postsgrid[/moz_widget]</div>
            </div>
            <!--/moz-module-->
        </div>
    </div>
';

$builder = preg_replace_callback('/(<div.*?class="moz-widget-id"[^>]*>)(.*?)(<\/div>)/i', function($matches) {
    $matches[0]();
}, $builder);
```

El resultado que recibo tras ejecutar el código es un fatal error :

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function [moz_widget]googlemaps[/moz_widget]()
>   in...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En tu código original faltaron unos brackets `[]` y las funciones no se llamaron bien.

Pero eso no era el problema principal, si no tu regex no funcionaba bien y la salida era:

`[moz_widget]googlemaps[\/moz_widget]`

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/eS0rI9/1)

con lo cual no ha podido llamar las funciones correctamente y respondió con un error.

Con el nuevo regex `/\[.*\](.*?)\[.*\]/` te elimina todos los brackets `[]` con su contenido y es entonces cuando llama correctamente tus funciones:

**[Demo funcionando en PHP](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e91d23a4543bbb3061bbfb74046b85e8ad6d642e)**

[Ver nuevo Regex](https://regex101.com/r/eZ1gT7/385)

```
$nuevoContenido = preg_replace_callback('/\[.*\](.*?)\[.*\]/i', function($matches) {

    return $matches[1]();

}, $builder);

echo $nuevoContenido;
```

Comment: Gracias @aldanux, ahora si que me la carga correctamente.